# algorithm2e + cleveref: problem with wrong reference to line numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e, cleveref

For some reason I do not understand, `cleveref`produces wrong references to line numbers of listings produces with the `algorithm2e` package. I hope that I did not miss a simple solution ...

My example is the following:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
Do something\;
Do something else\;\label{line}
\end{algorithm}

line~\ref{line} vs.\ \cref{line}.
\end{document}
```

The output (which you can also check [online](https://www.writelatex.com/101771vdggqn)) is

[image: Example output]

The `\ref` command works as expected (and refers to line 2) but the `\cref` command always refers to line 1 (no matter how many lines there are and which line I try to reference).

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Comment: I compiled your MWE and both refer to line 1 (except `cleveref` doesn't seem to know lines). But shouldn't you be ending your lines by `\\` so there actually is a linebreak?

Comment: It seems that the order in which one loads the `algorithm2e` and `cleveref` packes decides whether cleveref know what a line is. I added a link to an online LaTeX processor, which produces the same output. So far, using `\;` always worked for me.

Comment: `cleveref` has to be loaded after `hyperref`, which has to come after everything else, so I don't see how you would be able to change the order there. I don't know what the difference between this online compiler and mine is, but I don't see why yours knows lines with the above MWE, while mine doesn't, or why yours refers to different lines, while mine refers to the same (line 1...)

Comment: You may have discovered an incompatibility between the `cleveref` and `algorithm2e` packages, possibly introduced when the `algorithm2e` package was last updated, in Jan. 2013. I'd encourage you to contact the author of the `cleveref` package to make him aware of this issue. (The `cleveref` package was last updated in Sept. 2012...) You may find his contact information on the title page of the manual of the cleveref package.

Answer (score 10):

You found an oversight in the `cleveref` package. First, `algorithm2e` numbers the lines with the `AlgoLine` counter, and `cleveref` does not track that. So we need a

```
\crefalias{AlgoLine}{line}
```

to get that sorted.

Next, `cleveref` hacks into the `\label` command to write another label for its own use. In your example, the `.aux` contains

```
\newlabel{line}{{3}{1}{}{AlgoLine.1.3}{}}
\newlabel{line@cref}{{[line][1][]1}{1}}
```

The second line is written by `cleveref`. The offending part here is `{[line][1][]1}`, which is actually the content of `\cref@currentlabel`. Why is it wrong? While `\label` looks at `\@currentlabel`, `cleveref` uses its own `\cref@currentlabel` to determine what is been labeled. In order to keep that up to date, `cleveref` hacks into `\refstepcounter`, and updates `\cref@currentlabel` there. This works fine when `algorithm2e` is used without `hyperref`, but when `hyperref` is also loaded, the `AlgoLine` counter is updated with `\stepcounter`, and `cleveref` does not hack into that! This also means that `cleveref` will fail on all counters that are not (only) manipulated with `\refstepcounter`.

The solution is to also hack into `\stepcounter`, and update `\cref@currentlabel` there, too. The code for doing so is the same as for `\refstepcounter`. The complete code is then

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefalias{AlgoLine}{line}%

\makeatletter
\let\cref@old@stepcounter\stepcounter
\def\stepcounter#1{%
  \cref@old@stepcounter{#1}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
Do something\;
Do more\;
Do something else\;\label{line}
\end{algorithm}

line~\ref{line} vs.\ \cref{line}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! Just one point, though: Are you sure the issue is due to an oversight of the `cleveref` package? Could it, alternatively, be due to a change introduced when the `algorithm2e` package was last updated? The reason I raise this possibility is that the `cleveref` package (incarnation of Sept. 2012) claims to support the `algorithm2e` package -- see section 14.6.9. on p. 106 of the extended user guide. `Cleveref` executes, inter alia, `\crefalias{algocfline}{line}` for this purpose. This makes me wonder if `algorithm2e` recently renamed the counter `algocfline` to `AlgoLine`...

Comment: @Mico This might very well be. However, tracking counters by only monitoring `\refstepcounter` is fragile. By the way, the `algocfline` counter is still there, but it seems it is not used anymore.

Comment: Hacking into `\refcounter` breaks `\cref{}` with `enumerate` items for me (_reference format for label type Item undefined_). However, at the time of writing, with version 0.21.4 of cleverref, it seems that `\crefalias{AlgoLine}{line}` is all that is needed.

Answer (score 5):

mafp's solution is a bad idea, and should be avoided. Hacking `\stepcounter` is definitely the wrong thing to do, as it's used to step all kinds of counters unrelated to cross-references. Cross-reference counters *ought* to always be stepped by `\refstepcounter`, which additionally takes care of setting `\@currentlabel` appropriately. Thus "only monitoring `\refstepcounter`" is precisely the right thing to do. Most cross-referencing-related packaged (`hyperref`, `varioref`...) work this way.

Unfortunately, when `hyperref` is loaded, `algorithm2e` by-passes both `\refstepcounter` and `\H@refstepcounter` (`hyperref`'s version of the same), for reasons of its own (related to avoiding creating duplicate hyperlink anchors, I believe). This is an unfortunate choice of implementation, since by-passing the standard cross-reference machinery means packages like `cleveref` have to maintain fragile, specially-crafted support for `algorithm2e`. But that's LaTeX2e for you.

With `hyperref` loaded, `algorithm2e` has to take care of setting `\@currentlabel` itself (since it by-passes `\refstepcounter`). The correct solution is to modify `algorithm2e` so that it sets `\cref@currentlabel` at the same time as `\@currentlabel`. The latest version of `cleveref` (0.18.8) contains a fix for this.

It would be helpful if people reported bugs like this to the package author, instead of just posting them to stackexchange and using whatever ugly work-arounds are suggested in the replies. That way bugs get fixed in the package itself, and everyone benefits.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It's great to have you on this site!

Comment: Why so angry? Did I step on your toes somehow?

Comment: @mafp I wasn't angry at all - sorry if that's the way it came across. I just wanted to point out that hacking `\refstepcounter` is a bad idea, and should be avoided. (Trust me, as cleveref author, I know the kind of mess this gets you into :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for the incompatibility of `hyperref`+`algorithm2e` line numbering.
Just use `\nllabel` instead of `\label`. Worked for me.
Credits to Karthik: http://martinharrigan.blogspot.com.br/2007/11/using-hyperref-and-algorithm2e-line.html

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please consider to add more detail so that your post becomes a self-contained answer.

Comment: Have you tested this? Using `\nllabel` yields the same result as using `\label` (tested on [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com)).

Comment: I've tried this, but it's no help.

Comment: @lockstep the solution is self-contained, I just added a credit to someone else... is it wrong? Why did I get downvoted?